# Finding a basis for vector space of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Find a basis of space of 2×2 matrices $\{A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4\} $such that $ A_i^2=A_i$ for all i. I know how to find basis but I am unable to find such a property for this. Can you help me?
Two matrices can be :

````
[1,0,  and [0,0
 0,0].        0,1]
                            ```
````

Comment: Have you tried brute force? Take an arbitrary matrix $A$ and square it element by element.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand

Comment: You seem to be assuming that you need $4$ elements for this basis. Why do you assume this?

Comment: Also, the question phrasing is strange. Do you mean "find a basis for the subspace of $2\times 2$ matrices made up of all matrices $A$ such that $A^2=A$? Or even better, "Find a basis for the subspace $\{A|A^2=A\}$ of $2\times 2$ matrices". Because I doubt that is even a subspace.

Comment: Let$ V $be the space of 2 × 2 matrices over R. Find a basis$ \{A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4\} $for$ V $such that
$A^2_j = A_j $for each $j$..     it is mentioned in the question itself.   (This is the exact wording of the question)

Comment: OH OH OH I get it. You need just a basis for the space, and each member of the basis needs to have the property that it is its own square. I see. Well, what is a basis for $V$ that you know?

Comment: Set of 4 matrices such that in each matrix , only one element is non-zero (at 4 different positions for 4 matrices)

Comment: Do those meet your criteria?

Comment: With those the first two matrices in the basis, you now need one that has a non-zero upper-right element. Square $\bigl(\small{\matrix{a&1\\c&d}}\bigr)$ and see what constraints that generates.

Comment: It is a basis but the square of matrix A , such that  $A_{12} =1$ and $A_{ij} =0, ij \epsilon \{ 11,21,22\}$ is null matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding $[1,1,0,0]$ and $[0,0,1,1]$.

Comment: Yeah, got it...